# cube shrinks successively, when i rotate it with mouse..

Tags: java, netbeans, graphics, 3d, cube

i write the following code for a cube, that rotates on mouse motion,
but when i rotate the cube, or resize the Frame, the cube shrinks successively.
Is this the code or Frame, that is to be changed..
Pls Help,,

```
public class Cube extends javax.swing.JPanel implements MouseMotionListener        {


int node0[] = {-100, -100, -100};
int node1[] = {-100, -100,  100};
int node2[] = {-100,  100, -100};
int node3[] = {-100,  100,  100};
int node4[] = {100, -100, -100};
int node5[] = { 100, -100,  100};
int node6[] = {100,  100, -100};
int node7[] = {100,  100,  100};

int nodes[][] = {node0, node1, node2, node3, node4, node5, node6, node7};


int edge0[]  = {0, 1};
int edge1[]  = {1, 3};
int edge2[]  = {3, 2};
int edge3[]  = {2, 0};
int edge4[]  = {4, 5};
int edge5[]  = {5, 7};
int edge6[]  = {7, 6};
int edge7[]  = {6, 4};
int edge8[]  = {0, 4};
int edge9[]  = {1, 5};
int edge10[] = {2, 6};
int edge11[] = {3, 7};
int edges[][] = {edge0, edge1, edge2, edge3, edge4, edge5, edge6, edge7,    edge8, edge9, edge10, edge11};

// Rotate shape around the z-axis
public void rotateZ3D(int theta) {
double sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
double cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);

for (int n=0; n<8; n++) {
    int[] node = nodes[n];
    int x = node[0];
    int y = node[1];
    node[0] = (int) (x * cosTheta - y * sinTheta);
    node[1] = (int) (y * cosTheta + x * sinTheta);
 }
};

public void rotateX3D(int theta) {
double sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
double cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);

for (int n=0; n<8; n++) {
    int[] node = nodes[n];
    int y = node[1];
    int z = node[2];
    node[1] = (int) (y * cosTheta - z * sinTheta);
    node[2] = (int) (z * cosTheta + y * sinTheta);
}
};

public void rotateY3D(int theta) {
double sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
double cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);

for (int n=0; n<8; n++) {
    int[] node = nodes[n];
    int x = node[0];
    int z = node[2];
    node[0] = (int) (x * cosTheta - z * sinTheta);
    node[2] = (int) (z * cosTheta + x * sinTheta);
}
};

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

super.paintComponent(g);
// Draw edges
g.translate(150, 150);
rotateZ3D(60);
rotateY3D(60);
rotateX3D(60);


for (int e=0; e<12; e++) {
    int n0 = edges[e][0];
    int n1 = edges[e][1];
    int node0[] = nodes[n0];
    int node1[] = nodes[n1];


    g.drawLine(node0[0], node0[1], node1[0], node1[1]);

}
// Draw nodes

    for (int  n=0; n<8; n++) {
    int  node[] = nodes[n];
    g.drawOval(node[0], node[1], 5,5);
    g.drawString(n+"", node[0], node[1]);
} 
};

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
  JFrame j = new JFrame();
  Cube p = new Cube();
  j.add(p);
  j.addMouseMotionListener(p);
  j.setSize(500,500);
  j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  j.show();
    // TODO code application logic here
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
int x0 = me.getX();
int y0 = me.getY();
try {
    Thread.sleep(50);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Cube.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
int x1 = me.getX();
int y1 = me.getX();

rotateY3D(x1 - x0);
rotateX3D(y1 - y0);
repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
    }
}
```

suggest the solution code for it..
It's working fine , except that the cube is shrinking

Comment: `Thread.sleep` in the `mouseDragged` is a bad idea

Comment: self rotated mesh is not a good idea (on any variable type especially on `int` unless you perform just 90 degree rotations without precision loss). Better is having original mesh and create rotated on demand from it. That does not mean you need to have 2 meshes. For example you can compute the rotated vertex position when needed only and do not remember it...

Comment: yes, i know but i am a new learner in this topic, so don't know any function to get it, pls suggest better idea for it.. @MadProgrammer

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, maybe Swing `Timer` or `SwingWorker`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing the coordinates as `int`s.

Each time you do a rotation, you do a calculation which doesn't yield an integer; when you cast, you truncate the integer, rounding towards zero. Hence the shrinkage.

Use `double` instead, or, better, simply calculate a rotation matrix and apply that to the coordinates when you are rendering it.

Comment: actually i didn't cast it manually, the netbeans compiler suggest me to cast x*costheta-y*sintheta   to  int  @andyturner

Comment: Doesn't matter why you're doing it, you are truncating the number.